# iOS - bar button item on touch changes color

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have two view controllers, A and B, that are embedded in a navigation view controller and connected by a push segue. There is a back bar button item on B's navigation bar that is blue in color. Once the user enters B's scene, I set the navigation bar to be hidden in a animated manner. Here's the code for hiding the navigation bar in B:

```
- (void)hideNavigationBar
{
    if (self.navigationBarHidden == NO)
    {
        [UIView animateWithDuration:UINavigationControllerHideShowBarDuration animations:^{
            self.navigationController.navigationBar.alpha = 0.0;
            self.previewCollectionView.alpha = 0.0;
        } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
            self.navigationBarHidden = YES;
        }];
    }
}
```

The user can bring the navigation bar back by tapping on the screen. Here's the problem: suppose the user taps on the back bar button in B and hold it, the back button becomes whitish. Then the navigation bar disappears in an animated manner. If the user then taps to bring the navigation bar back, the back button remains whitish, but it should be blue. So is there anyway to toggle the color of the back button back?

Comment: Is there a reason you don't use `UINavigationController`'s `setNavigationBarHidden:animated:`?  If you use that instead, does it work?

Comment: This comes from some other people's code. But I can try that.

Comment: Ok, so the code you mentioned hides the navigation bar by pushing it up, instead of making it fade slowly. I want to hide the  previewCollectionView at the bottom in a similar manner (pushing it down). Is there anyway I can do that?

Comment: you may do this in your code self.navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = [UIColor blueColor];

Comment: @mownier Unfortunately it doesn't work....